Lack of strong law for the Saint Petersburg paradox
The Saint Petersburg paradox can be formulated as follows: Suppose we have a lottery whose payout ${X}$ takes taking values in the powers of two ${2,2^2,2^3,\dots}$ with
$\displaystyle  {\bf P}( X = 2^i ) = 2^{-i}$
for ${i=1,2,\dots}$. The question is to work out what is the “fair” or “breakeven” price to pay for a lottery ticket. If one plays this lottery ${n}$ times, the total payout is ${S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n}$ where ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ are independent copies of ${X}$, so the question boils down to asking what one expects the value of ${S_n/n}$ to be. Following the analysis in the note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/275a-notes-3-the-weak-and-strong-law-of-large-numbers/comment-page-2/#comment-685138, it can be shown that for large $n$,
$\displaystyle  {\bf P}(|\frac{S_n}{n \log_2 n} - 1| \geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}) = O( \frac{1}{\log^{1/2} n})$.
Show that $\displaystyle {\frac{S_n}{n \log_2 n}}$ is almost surely unbounded. (Hint: it suffices to show that ${X_n / n \log_2 n}$ is almost surely unbounded. For this, use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.)
Question: According to the hint, we want to establish the claim by showing that $\displaystyle {\bf P}(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n/n\log_2 n = \infty) = 1$, yet the second Borel-Cantelli lemma will give instead that ${\bf P}(\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} X_n/n\log_2 n = \infty) = 1$ (which also seems to be able to give the  claim), is there a misunderstanding here regarding the hint and how should one obtain the result?
Edit: One can simply aruge as in this paper: https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.47.3.330 and we're done.

Track : What is $\limsup$  of $ X_n$ according to the definition of $X_n$ ?

@EDX: $\lim \sup X_n = \infty$ by definition, yet we need information on the lim sup of $X_n/n\log_2 n$.

And so with the initial definition of $X$, expressing $X_n/n\log(n)$

@EDX: The author clarified the wording of the hint by by saying that showing the limit superior of the $X_n/n \log n$ is infinite is equivalent to showing that the sequence $X_n/n \log n$ is unbounded. The question is now solved, thanks for the attention.

Ok nice thats cool !
